# de morgan's law implemention using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, demorgans-law

- expression 1: (A and B or (not C))
- expression 2: not((not A) or (not B) and C)

I want to change the expression 2 to expression1. So the expression can be expressed as a tree like the picture below. That means "not" operation can only exist in leaf node.

[image]

The transform is based on [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

**And here is my question:**

Is there a C/C++ library implement this function? I don't know much about C/C++ library. I searched [GMP](https://gmplib.org/devel/GMPng.html) and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ but didn't find the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: your tree is an AST, also called EBNF/BNF tree, or syntax tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree ; the real problem is: what kind of language are you parsing ?

Comment: Seems to me that you could start at the root, transform `NOT (a {AND|OR} b)` to `(NOT a) {OR|AND} (NOT b)` if needed, and then process each child similarly -- making sure to eliminate double negatives.  You don't really need a library for this.

Comment: You're not telling us enough to provide a guaranteed useful answer.  If we presume that you'll put the logical expression into say a `boost::graph` or `lemon` (can Google them), then of course you could search down through the tree to see if some nodes represented an "expression 2" situation and simplify it ala "expression 1".  There are many graph libraries available, but I think you'll have to write your own struct to represent logical operations and/or values, and your own De Morgan substitution code.  Dubious use without something to populate the graph from, and use the results for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since there doesn't exist some libraries, I will write the code by myself.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is simple when you think about it recursively:

- `not (X and Y)` ==> `(not X) or (not Y)`
- `not (X or Y)` ==> `(not X) and (not Y)`

so in C++:

```
struct Node {
    virtual ~Node() {};
    virtual Node *copy() = 0;
    virtual Node *negation() = 0;

private:
    // Taboo
    Node(const Node&);
    Node& operator=(const Node&);
};

struct AndNode : Node {
    Node *left, *right;
    AndNode(Node *left, Node *right) : left(left), right(right) {}
    ~AndNode() { delete left; delete right; }
    Node *copy() { return new AndNode(left->copy(), right->copy()); }
    Node *negation();
};

struct OrNode : Node {
    Node *left, *right;
    OrNode(Node *left, Node *right) : left(left), right(right) {}
    ~OrNode() { delete left; delete right; }
    Node *copy() { return new OrNode(left->copy(), right->copy()); }
    Node *negation();
};

struct NotNode : Node {
    Node *x;
    NotNode(Node *x) : x(x) {}
    ~NotNode() { delete x; }
    Node *copy() { return new NotNode(x->copy()); }
    Node *negation();
};

struct VarNode : Node {
    std::string var;
    VarNode(const std::string& var) : var(var) {}
    Node *copy() { return new VarNode(var); }
};
```

The `negation` code for `and` and `or` operations simply applies De Morgan's law thus "pushing" the negation down the tree

```
Node *AndNode::negation() {
    return new OrNode(left->negation(), right->negation());
}

Node *OrNode::negation() {
    return new AndNode(left->negation(), right->negation());
}
```

The negation of a negation instead does the elision simplification

```
Node *NotNode::negation() {
    return x->copy();
}
```

Only a leaf node gets actually wrapped in a negation operation

```
Node *VarNode::negation() {
    return new NotNode(this->copy());
}
```

As you see the Morgan's law is just two lines, everything else is how to represent an expression tree in C++. It doesn't make sense to have a library to implement De Morgan's transform only because once you have the representation it's absolutely trivial.

An implementation with wrappers to be able to work with different tree representations would be 99% boilerplate and interface code to implement a two-liner (a total nonsense).

Just implement it directly with whatever tree representation you have.

Comment: While this illustrates the principle nicely, please don’t ever write code like this in C++. Use value objects and/or smart pointers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Admittedly I've an insane passion for naked pointers and tend to overuse them a bit. However showing that the issue is the tree representation (and not De Morgan's law algorithm) is actually the point of the answer.